# tfs 2017 - scrum template - missing statechanged field in some work items

Tags: tfs

Noticed StateChanged field is missing within XML definitions of some work items in scrum template of tfs 2017 RTM : pbi, testplan, testsuite, feebackrequest, codereviewrequest, and some more.

I assume i should add it manually to them. Right ?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the `State Change Date` field, yes, by default it's not added in some work items in scrum template.

Actually the control is not added to layout eventhough in the existing work items such as `Bug`, `Feature`. That means, you cannot see the field in work item layout. However you can add the control to display the field based on your requirements.

Yes, you can also add the `State Change Date` field manually to the work items which not exsiting in them. See [Add a field, or apply a rule, or change an attribute for details.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/add-modify-field#add-a-field-or-apply-a-rule-or-change-an-attribute)

You can also use the [TFS Process Template Editor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KarthikBalasubramanianMSFT.TFSProcessTemplateEditor) to edit the WITs definitions.

**Field:**

```
<FieldDefinition name="State Change Date" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StateChangeDate" type="DateTime">
  <WHENCHANGED field="System.State">
    <SERVERDEFAULT from="clock" />
  </WHENCHANGED>
  <WHENNOTCHANGED field="System.State">
    <READONLY />
  </WHENNOTCHANGED>
</FieldDefinition>
```

**Layout Control:**

```
<Group Label="Status">
  <Column PercentWidth="100">
    <Control FieldName="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StateChangeDate" Type="DateTimeControl" Label="State Change Date:" LabelPosition="Left" />
  </Column>
</Group>
```

**Page Section:**

```
  <Section>
    <Group Label="Status">
      <Control Label="State Change Date:" Type="DateTimeControl" FieldName="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StateChangeDate" />
    </Group>
  </Section>
```

[image]

Comment: @moital Have you resolved the issue by the answer? any update?